# Swashbuckle Complex Objects

Tags: c#, user-interface, swashbuckle

Given an object parameter such as:

```
public class XYZ {
      public List<ABC> listABC { get; set; }
}

public class ABC {
     public string A { get; set; }
     public string B { get; set; }
     public string C { get; set; }
}
```

I know it is possible to get Swashbuckle to show XYZ.listABC in the UI and then to enter the list in the text box if you use [FromUri(Name="XYZ")] before the parameter.

Is there a way to expose the list object ABC in the UI instead of having a generic text box for XYZ.listABC?